# Applying a regex to a String created form a small byte array buffer buffering a huge file

Tags: java, regex, arrays

I'm reading in a file which I can't buffer all at once, as its size ranges from 256MB upto ~2GB in size.

Once the file is opened, I read a chunk of it into a byte array, say 512 bytes, convert it into a String and run a regex over it, and if the pattern is detected, my program makes a note of it.

The problem I'm having is that my program is missing a lot of the locations in the file where it should be detecting the pattern.

I'm 90% sure the problem is that whilst the pattern is there, it's not complete, as it's going outside the length of the buffer.  The pattern I'm looking for is eight bytes in length, so for example, the first four bytes of the pattern are at the last four positions in the array; so when it is filled again, the first four bytes of the array are the last four of the pattern.  As such, my regex always fails.

I'm guessing what I need to do is to fill the buffer, then when it fills it again, retain the last 20 or so bytes in there, so that it will not miss any of the patterns I'm looking for.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Tony

Comment: Regexes run on character strings, not byte arrays.

Comment: Sorry, once the byte array has been filled, I'm creating a string out of the data in there

Comment: Is it a text file? Can you read it a line at a time?

Comment: The file is essentially a binary file.  It contains a whole heap of seemingly random characters.  I'm using ISO-8859-1 character encoding for it.  Problem is I just need to keep on moving the buffer along so that it doesn't cut the pattern in half.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can't apply a Java regular expression to a byte array. You have to apply it to a `String`. So, you must be converting from `byte[]` to `String`, and you may (a) be using the wrong encoding, or (b) truncating the string in the middle.

Once you've gotten past this, you need to have use a streaming discipline to reframe what you read. I can describe one that might or might not apply:

1. Read a big blob of data into a buffer.
2. Find the last sentence boundary in the buffer.
3. Process from the start to the boundary.
4. Move the remainder to the front of the buffer.
5. Refill the rest of the buffer from the source.
6. lather, rinse, repeat.

If this is really an ordinary file of characters, then modify as follows:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(inputByteStream, Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Then apply the algorithm above to avoid buffer boundary conditions.

Comment: Seems to me he should simply use an InputStreamReader with the right decoder. I just cannot understand why people keep trying to handle encoded byte arrays when they need characters.  Set the decoding once and forget about it.

Comment: That's exactly what I need to do!  I'm just not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo-code for what you should do:

```
while true:
   read 512 bytes into new buffer
   if eof:
       break
   concatenate with previous buffer (and only previous buffer)
   run regex on concatenated buffer
```

Comment: Only works if all the data fits in memory, but fine in that case.

Comment: @bmarguiles - I'm guessing, if he's running java, he has room for two 512 byte buffers

Answer (score 2):

One interesting possible solution is to note that regex methods take input as a [`CharSequence`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) rather than `String` (and, as far as I can see, they never call `CharSequence.toString()`).

So, you can implement a `CharSequence` that fetches characters from a file without loading the whole file into memory. If your file has an encoding where characters take the constant number of bytes (ASCII, UTF-16), you can almost directly adapt `RandomAccessFile` to `CharSequence` (though I'm not sure about performance in this case, perhaps you will need some buffering).

Answer (score 1):

You can load your file in a [Circular Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer), check constantly for that pattern and delete checked data.

Comment: I think a circular buffer sounds like exactly what I need.  I shall read up on that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your pattern is 8 bytes long, just run an extra regex check, concatenating the last and first 7 bytes (14 total) of two consecutive bufferings. That way you'll be sure you don't miss any, and it fits in rougly the same memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to solve this, but these two strike me as the easiest to implement:

- Retain the last seven bytes from the previous buffer when you load the next one. Concatenate those seven bytes with the first seven bytes of the new buffer, and run a separate test for the 14-byte "seam" before testing the whole buffer.
- Put a 7-byte overlap between the two buffers; i.e. keep the buffer size at 512 bytes, but load the second buffer from byte 504 (I'm using zero-index here, so this would be the 505th byte in the file).

The second option is likely to be significantly faster, but the first one should be a snap to code. Choose whichever fits your situation.